# List item height changes when item image is set

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

I want to have a list view with items that consist of an image thumbnail on the left and some text on the right. The list view is declared like this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/imageList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The item itself like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_cross" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, at some point in my code I assign an adapter to a `ListView`:

```
val lv = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.imageList)
lv.adapter = ImageListBinder(this, cachedImages!!)
```

And `ImageListBinder.getView` looks like this:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View
{
    val view = convertView ?: createView()
    val holder = view.tag as ViewHolder

    holder.textView.text = "Some text"
    val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(images[position].localPath.absolutePath)
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp)

    return view
}

private fun createView() : View
{
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null)
    view.tag = ViewHolder(view.findViewById(R.id.imageView), view.findViewById(R.id.textView))
    return view
}

private class ViewHolder(val imageView: ImageView, val textView: TextView)
```

The issue is that when those images get assigned to ImageViews, the height of the list item becomes equal to the original height of the image (so if I add the 100x1600 image to the list, the item height becomes 1600 pixels) despite the fact that `LinearLayout`'s height is fixed and `ImageView`'s height is set to `match_parent`:
[image: looong list items]

What am I doing wrong here? How to make list item height to stay as specified?

I tried reading ImageView's height and width before calling the `setImageBitmap`, followed by resetting them after, that didn't help, I also tried setting the `android:adjustViewBounds="false"` and `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` which didn't change anything either. The only thing that worked so far was setting the `android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"` on the `ImageView`, but I don't want to set image view height so hard. At least no until I understand why I see what I see now.

Comment: Your layout has a default alternative in android which I hope will work!

Comment: @Xenolion, alternatives would be nice to know, but at this point I am most interested in explanation why I see the behavior I see and what do I set it up to behave like I want it to behave without constraining it too much.

Comment: `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` why false put true????? I think it should be true for you to get what you want?

Comment: Tried that, too. No change

Answer (score 0):

Its because the height of your ListView is match_parent. Change the height of the ListView to wrap_content.

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/imageList"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why do you think `match_parent` for the `ListView` is wrong? And, no, it does not work. With `wrap_content` `ListView` disappears completely.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

For example, please have a look on following screenshots

With  `android:adjustViewBounds="false"`

[image]

With  `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

[image]

Comment: Tried that. For some reason I don't see any effect whatsoever, and anyway, I want all list items to be of the same height.

Comment: What's your compile sdk ?

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 26`, `minSdkVersion 14`

Answer (score -1):

In item Layout change the ImageView layout_width and layout_height to fixed size as:
for example:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="150dp" 
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_cross" />
```

change "150dp" as you like.

Comment: That's not what I want. I thought I pretty clearly stated that in my post